# Glassfish logging suddenly stops

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3

We're running many instances of glassfish in a linux box and suddenly they stop logging (a blank server.log file is created and no logging data is appended to it).

it happens after something like a week of normal logging.

#### How can I fix it?

#### How can I diagnose the problem -there's something like a log of the logger internals :p-?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glassfish 3.1.1 suddenly stopped writing to server.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373629/glassfish-3-1-1-suddenly-stopped-writing-to-server-log)

Answer (score 5):

Check the logging properties of your domain (domain-dir/config/logging.properties). If there is nothing logged at all the GFFileHandler logging level might be set to "OFF" ([Glassfish-18205 bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18205)).

Try to set it to a different level with CLI:

> asadmin set-log-levels
>   com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler=ALL

This sometimes happens while playing with logging levels in glassfish.

Comment: could you please tell me how or what to do to get my trusted log back!