# Glassfish 3.1.1 suddenly stopped writing to server.log

Tags: logging, configuration, glassfish

I changed one of the log levels in the admin console, and Glassfish 3.1.1 stopped writing anything into the domain1/logs/server.log. I since reverted the change and tried restarting the server a couple times. Here's the last thing it logged:

```
[#|2012-02-20T16:44:53.738-0800|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;
_ThreadName=Thread-7;|com.sun.webui.jsf.component.DropDown::The current value of component form1:basicTable:rowGroup1:6:col3:level does not match any of the selections. 
Did you forget to reset the value after changing the options? |#]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you encountered [Glassfish-18205 bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18205).
GFFileHandler logging level might be set to "OFF".

Try to set it to a different level with CLI:

```
asadmin set-log-levels com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler=ALL
```

You could use the admin console as well, but the drop down menu there doesn't allow to select the log level "ALL" (although this is a valid log level). Choose one of the other options there.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what happened. I also set the "javax.enterprise.system.core.security" logger to to FINEST. The solution worked.

Comment: The problem still exists in Payara 4.1.2.172 and this was still a valid solution for me.