# logging and/or debugging on remote Glassfish

Tags: debugging, logging, glassfish

I have a problem.
I deployed a web service on a remote Glassfish instance. Now I need to have some simple log or debug system in order to correct my code( using simple prints would be preferable).
My idea was to use the glassfish log file as I can access it from admin GUI, but it doesn't work; I'm not able to write into this file. 
Any idea to solve this problem? Or any other method that I can use?
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, if you use the java logging api, and enable logging for your application on the glassfish management console, your logging gets picked up by glassfish.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beafm.html#scrolltoc

Comment: @flup Following other guides, I have this very simple class:
`code`public class NewClass {
    
    private static Logger log;
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
{


System.out.println("log");

log = Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()); 
log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
log.info("log info"); 
log.severe("log severe");
log.fine("log fine");
log.finer("log finer");
log.finest("log finest");
log.config("log config");
log.warning("log warning");


}`code`
But nothing appears in the log file

Comment: Looks good. Though for testing I'd start with a `log.severe()` to make sure you don't get filtered out. I found a bit more detailed link about how to administer logging: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FaqConfigureLogging From that link: "If you use the java.util.logging system in your own application, then you can add properties here to affect your loggers directly."

Comment: Oh and wait... the main method won't get called when you deploy this to glassfish.

Comment: @flup It seems that I do not have the section mentioned in your last link when it is mentioned :"Of special note here is the Properties section at the bottom of the page."

Comment: edit: I solved the problem locally(jsf welcome page that calls the method that logs), but not in my remote example. I put logging methods in a web service, but when I call it, nothing happens.

Comment: What logging handler is defined on your glassfish server?

Answer (score 5):

Glassfish's default logging solution is to use the `java.util.logging` (JUL) logger.

You can use it in your code as follows:

```
package org.example.something;
```

[...]

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

[...]

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
logger.severe("severe");
logger.info("info");
logger.fine("fine");
```

You can administrate glassfish logging through the administration console which runs on `http://servername:4848/`. There are other ways too.

In Glassfish 3.1, which is the one I tried, you can set the log level for each logger on the Configurations, your-server-config, Logger Settings page, Log Levels tab.
You can press Add Logger.
You give the package of your class as a Logger Name, so in this example `org.example.something` and select the log level. Anything on or above this level will get logged, as long as the log level for `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler` is also set on or below this level. See [Glassfish 3.1.1 suddenly stopped writing to server log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373629/glassfish-3-1-1-suddenly-stopped-writing-to-server-log)

Press save and the changes should take effect immediately.
In the General tab, you find the configuration of where the logging will end up.

You can browse the logging in the administration tool too. Select Server, the General tab, View Log Files.

Comment: I'm trying to log on a remote Glassfish 3 version, what you are saying regarding 3.1 seems not to be present: I can not add any new rule. The only interesting thing that I notices is that there is a rule for "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler" which is set to "FINEST"

Comment: I have tried on an older version of Glassfish, there I found the same settings on "Application Server", "Logging", "Log Levels", "Add Property". The tiny print says "Click Add Property to set log levels for application loggers." I'd expect the format is key: `org.example.something` and value: 'FINEST'.

Comment: In my version, I have to go in "Configuration" -> "Logger settings" -> "Log Levels"