# Glassfish Logs in Idea 12

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using GF 3 with Idea 12, and am unable to see the Glassfish logs without tailing them (Ubuntu) in the file system.

I have the checkbox activated as per the screenshot, but I still only see basic messages like these, but no debug or println messages.

Did I miss a step, or misread the doc?

```
Admin Port: 4848  
Command start-domain executed successfully.
Connected to server
```

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

Comment: I think the Glassfish log file does not show messages written to standard out, but log entries created using Java Util Logging, instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414643/logging-and-or-debugging-on-remote-glassfish/14415792#14415792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your application server's run/debug configuration in IDEA to automatically tail a particular log file (see the "Logs" tab in your server's run/debug config).

Also make sure that you did not filter logs using the "Log level" combobox in the upper right part of the tab which displays your logs.