# SEC1111: Cannot load group for JDBC realm user

Tags: java, security, jpa, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I apparently doing something wrong in the configuration of a jdbcRealm. But I don't know what exactly.

[image: error]

This is my configuration:

[image: config]

What else is needed to help me?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gebruiker")
public class User implements Serializable  {

@Id  @Column(name="User_NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "groep_gebruiker")
private Role rol;

@Entity
@Table(name = "groep")
public class Role implements Serializable {
@Id 
private String rol;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rol")

private Collection<User> gebruikers = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java EE declarative security, Cannot load group for JDBC realm user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483132/java-ee-declarative-security-cannot-load-group-for-jdbc-realm-user)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is because you did not create a JDBC realm user /Hans/

Comment: In my database in the gebruiker table there is a user with the name Hans. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: yes, I also made a user admin and he got the same error. Would it help if I post all info from inside my database?

Comment: @Aldwoni is your user column in the user table the same name as the user column in the USER_GROUPS table? because the matching is done by the column names.

Comment: I have a gebruiker table with a NAME column.(my current user name column) And I have a groep_gebruiker table with a User_NAME column(my current group name column). both with Hans in it.

Comment: @aldwoni name the columns the same, the matching is done by column names

Comment: I currently get the following error: jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason, I changed the gebruiker table to also have User_NAME so the columns have exactly the same name

Comment: I added some code to the question, I hope it helps you